# getting file updates from ftp server using inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

i am trying to get file updates from ftp server (and if any new file is added) but the code is getting the file updates from local directory by creating new folder of the given name

```
@Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = 
            new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteFileSeparator("/");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}



    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(fileSynchronizer);
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("/FTP_Test"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }
private SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(host);
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password); 
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: Your question is not clear; the synchronizer will fetch new files and copy them to the local directory; a message will be emitted for each new one found. If you manually add files that that directory, they will be emitted too.

Comment: thanq sir for the response.  the code is actually working the only thing i added is                                                                                                                                  sf.setClientMode(2); in the ftpSessionFactory()...........                                                     instead of copying files to local directory can i add them to another remote ftp server?